# Retrieving Ms-access form properties in python

Tags: python, ms-access

I want to retrieve ms-access form dimensions through python, getting the "width" is no problem, but "height" is not a direct property but consists of partial heights of sections.  In VBA these can be taken by Form!fName.section(n).height.  In python this fails.  Does anyone know the direct access to these properties.  The code used is

```
formNames = []
strDbName = 'D:\\Python\\workspace\\Test_MDB\\kaders.mdb'
oApp = Dispatch("Access.Application")
oApp.Visible = True
win32api.keybd_event(0x10, 0x10, 0, 0)
oApp.OpenCurrentDatabase(strDbName)
win32api.keybd_event(0x10, 0x10, 2, 0)
print("Program start .....")
for form in oApp.CurrentProject.AllForms:
    formName = form.name                # get form name and open 
    oApp.DoCmd.OpenForm(formName, 1)    # acDesign = 1
    frm = oApp.Forms(formName)          # point to form

    print (frm.width)
    print (frm.section(0).height)
```

last line crashes with

print (frm.section(0).height)

File ">", line 2, in section

pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352573, 'can't find member.', None, None)

any ideas?
thanks,
Walter

Comment: Try using `Detail0`, an equivalent [form section property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835642.aspx) or use square brackets `[0]`. Usually parentheses after a named object denotes a function in Python.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but tried them both before      
section[0]  gives as error
"    print (frm.section[0].height)
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable"      
and Detail0 returns error     
"    raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr))
AttributeError: <unknown>.Detail0 "

Answer (score 0):

To get the section for form's height, simply reference the named section of form without need of a number index: Detail, FormHeader, PageHeader.

Also, I adjusted your code somewhat to convert [twips to inches](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/76388) in form's dimensions in print statements and wrapped loop in a `try/except` (the counterpart to VBA's `On Error` handle) as you want to always uninitialize com objects from memory after runtime of script regardless of errors.

```
import win32api
import win32com.client   

strDbName = 'D:\\Python\\workspace\\Test_MDB\\kaders.mdb'

oApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Access.Application")
oApp.Visible = True
win32api.keybd_event(0x10, 0x10, 0, 0)
oApp.OpenCurrentDatabase(strDbName)
win32api.keybd_event(0x10, 0x10, 2, 0)
print("Program start .....")

try:
    for form in oApp.CurrentProject.AllForms:
        formName = form.name                # get form name and open 
        oApp.DoCmd.OpenForm(formName, 1)    # acDesign = 1
        frm = oApp.Forms(formName)          # point to form

        print (form.name)                   
        print ((frm.width)/1440)            # convert twips to inchdes (1440 twips = 1 inch)
        print ((frm.Detail.height/1440))    # convert twips to inchdes (1440 twips = 1 inch)        
        print ("-----------------------")
        oApp.DoCmd.Close(2, formName)       # closing form to remove instance (in case of subforms)

except Exception as e :
        print (e)

oApp.DoCmd.CloseDatabase                    # closing database to release from memory
oApp = None                                 # uninitializing com object
```

Comment: You're right using the name of the section(s), only I am trying to read/convert a rather big number of forms to HTML + CSS, and I cant be sure that the creator has not changed the section(s) default name(s) or uses a different language.  Other Access languages gives other names, as mine is Dutch hence "FormHeader" becomes "Formulierkoptekst" .  Inspecting that manually is not an option

Comment: Did you test code? Access runs dependent on the current user's regional language settings. Hence, whatever your language, amend code accordingly. If attempting to run Python script on different language machines, then conditionally call the height line with `if`. Please test out the English vs Dutch version on your end.

Comment: Did the test, used an English version of "Northwind" and a Dutch test form..  Header names are as told..  is how I found out  :-)

Comment: Also if someone uses a own name for a section e.g. "my_top_line", I have the same problem to retrieve that.

Meanwhile I have a workaround, by finding the most lowest point of any control in a section, using the section number in the control, and taking that as height, adding a little bottom padding

Comment: I am not understanding. Access forms only have five [section types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835642.aspx) in its property, none of which are user-defined: Detail, FormHeader, FormFooter, PageHeader, PageFooter. Reports have 9 [section types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192668.aspx). The script opens specific form in loop of all forms and retrieves width and detail height of that specific form. Nothing is called by name.

Comment: The number of sections and standard names are correct, hope I can explain, translated from Dutch Access 2007...    

open a form in edit mode, point to header bar, in properties take tab "all", there you can name the header different than the default "FormHeader"   e.g. "banana"

Also then I can get section height by "frm.banana.height"  same as getting it by that name in Access in direct "? me.banana.height" in VBA

and its those changed names that I cant retrieve direct from a property..  at least none I know  :-)

Comment: I understand you can name those section but why would you even need to? Did Python script fail on your end? Did it miss a height dimension? Why even retrieve those custom names if they can be open-ended as you mention? We can loop through all standard sections of specific form, still avoiding names. Notice you never reference form's custom name.

Comment: I know changing the names is not "best practice" but in my conversion program I want to cover the most possible, including the "unconventional" use of names by different creators.  For my development version I will take your advice and keep it to standard names in Dutch and English.  Thanks for your input  :-)

Comment: Got it. Please accept my answer for others to know original issue is resolved. Good luck. See you around SO.